# InAppBrowser loadstop fires twice

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, capacitor, ionic5

I am working on ionic 5 with angular and I need an inappbrowser to open an array of URLs of a website one after the other on click of some button on the webpage. The array has last URL as `https://www.example.com/#close` which makes it close the browser. So I did something like this

```
const browser = this.iab.create(arr[0], '_blank', {hideurlbar : 'yes'} );
    let i = 1;

    browser.on('beforeload').subscribe((event) => {
      if (event.url == 'https://www.example.com/#close') {
        browser.close();
        this.presentAlert("You have seen all the Links");
      }
    });

    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
      browser.executeScript(
        {
          code :
          `
          localStorage.setItem('next', '${arr[i]}')
          var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("fr66n");
          var myFunction = function(event) {
            window.location = localStorage.getItem('next');
          };
          for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
              elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
          }
          `
        }
       );
       i++;
   });
```

But the problem here is, loadstop runs twice on every click making the browser load alternate URLs.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?
I have the same problem with InAppBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with InAppBrowser.

However, I found a **temporary solution** which consists in putting a setTimeOut in "code" and use "loadstart" instead of "loadstop":

```
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
browser.executeScript(
    {
      code :
      `
        setTimeout(() => {

            localStorage.setItem('next', '${arr[i]}')
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("fr66n");
            var myFunction = function(event) {
                window.location = localStorage.getItem('next');
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
            }
            
        }, 1000);
      `
    }
   );i++;
});
```